# How to send a Struts Action Form object to EJB session's bean method?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts, ejb-3.0

I have Struts action form Object called `register` i need to send the action form object to a session bean method as parameter so I done the following

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception 
{
    Register register = (Register)form;
    home.registerUser(register);
    return mapping.findForward("success");
}
```

Where `home` is the stub to access session bean and `registerUser` is the session bean method.

Now the problem is i am not able to reference the `Register` class in the session bean.

Please help me how to send the `register` object to the session bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create Entity class object related to your register data and add the form data onto the received object and send it back to EJB for storing at the database.

```
    Register register = (Register)form;        
    Customer customer = new Customer();        
    customer.setUsername(register.getName());
    customer.setPassword(register.getPassword());
    customer.setEmail_id(register.getEmailid());
    String result = home.registerUser(customer);
```

`register` - It is the ActionForm Object.

`customer` - Entity class object for the registration table.

`home` - It is the Home Interface reference object.

`registerUser` - It is the method in the session bean which contain code to `perist` the data onto the database.

Answer (score 0):

In `Register` form, create a method `registerUser` and from there you call your **SessionBean** method `home.registerUser(this)`. Now, In action's `execute` method call `register.registerUser()`.

Comment: Actually the problem is I cant able to reference the Register object in the session bean of EJB Tier. I can able to send the Register object from Web Tier to EJB Tier